# Message Box Buttons Name Change possible in C#?

Tags: c#

I need to change the Message Box Buttons Ok and Cancel Text to Update and AddNew?
Is it possible in C#.NET or I need to create a form and customize it?
Kindly help me in this.

Comment: Create a form. From what I've seen `MessageBox` doesn't allow it, and it's not a limitation of .NET's forms implementation, it's the underlying Win32 API who doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible using a MessageBoxManager.dll, which you can get in the following link,

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18399/Localizing-System-MessageBox

Answer (score 1):

The `MessageBox` class does not provide you with option to change the button text. This [codeproject article, Localizing System MessageBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18399/Localizing-System-MessageBox) allows you do that by simply adding and using the class in your project

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the text in MessageBox Buttons.To implement the scenario you can have your custom message box.Which can be build using User Control and show it as a Dialog whenever needed.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the text of a button on a MessageBox is not possible by default. While the text might be changeable through fake localizations, this does not seem like a good way to do it from my point of view. I encourage creating a separate form.